# How can i get the metrics score of LCP?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I'm trying to get the metric score of the LCP by calling a get method via API. It returns to me a json file, but when i'm searching for LCP it is giving to me: "Score":"Null".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, i need to get the metrics score for the LCP from a json file. The json file is recieved from a request to pageinsights, when i wan't to see the LCP Score it gives me null like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RITSn.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all of the information that you can directly into the body of the question. Please also post the JSON as well formatted text, not as a picture.